# System config requirements for PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

everybody. I have 4 GB of RAM and intel core i5. Not very advanced, but it's still a rather decent notebook configuration and should be enough for coding.
I　ran Pycharm (PyCharm Edu 3.5(64) today and my computer just froze down. I waited for 30 mins, but Pycharm was still busy with its inspections and I stopped it, couldn't wait for such a long time.
I want to ask more experienced guys: how many RAM is enough for a really comfortable work? I don't really want to disable the functionality of IDE. I used Spider first, but its doesn't have code auto-completion and that's really not very convenient. Or perhaps I'd better to use other IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm recommend 2GB of ram but the actual RAM required for your system depends on what all other process are running.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/requirements-for-pycharm.html#d360842e117

I would say check your system memory usage when PyCharm is not running. PyCharm could take anywhere between 500MB-1GB of additional memory. So if your system is already on low memory then its time to upgrade your RAM.

Comment: I added 4GB more, now it's 8 GB DDR3 and HD, not SDD. I started PyCharm, at least the system is not slowing down now. So, real requirement is more than 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

I work with PyCharm (at work) with 6GB of RAM (not with a notebook) and its ok. Before that I was working with 2GB and it was crazy because all time it was frozing and i was need to reset the computer a lot of times during the day.

But I think that with 8GB could be so better than 6GB.
I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Yep,  thanks. I can figure out that I need to add another 4 GB to my RAM. It looks like games, just impossible to have a good play on weakest configuration...

Comment: It's so easy to change it, don't worry dude and youtube have the best free tutorials! jejeje